# Having a SLURM job check how long until itself ends

Tags: jobs, slurm

I am wondering if I can get a SLURM job to check how long it will keep on running before the amount of time specified by `#SBATCH --time` is passed.

I thought of a solution, but it seems horrible to me: I know I can see how long the job has been running whith `squeue` and its options. So I could have the job calling `squeue` when I want the check to be done, store the output of the command in a variable (or a file) and read the amount of time since the job has started. Something like this

```
 status=$(squeue -j $job_id)    //Alternatively squeue -u my_username
 status_array=($status)
 time_since_start=${status[13]}
```

Then it would only be a matter of computing the time difference. The problem with the above approach is that the job needs to know its own `job_id`. Even if I use `-u my_username`, I still need the `job_id` if I have more than one job running simultaneously, which is my typical case. The only way I can see to get the job to know its `id` is to instruct the script that launches it to write such `id` in a file and then have the job read that file.

I am wondering whether it exists a simpler/more elegant solution, maybe using SLURM commands (something like `squeue -magic_option`) but I could not find anything.

Comment: You could use `${SLURM_JOB_ID}` to get the job ID you are interested in (https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html).

Comment: @Poshi I don't get it: you mean that if I write `id=${SURLM_JOB_ID}` inside the SLURM job then `id` will contain the id of the job itself? Could you make it a complete answer...?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I didn't made a complete answer because I'm not really answering what you asked (how to compute pending running time), just giving you a hint to fill one gap in your knowledge that will allow you to complete your task in the way you originally intend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `squeue` command can give you the answer:

```
squeue -h -j $SLURM_JOB_ID -O TimeLeft
```

To further test that value, which will be in the `hh:mm:ss` format, you can use `awk` to get a corresponding number of minutes:

```
squeue -h -j SLURM_JOB_ID -O TimeLeft |  awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60)  }'
```

If the jobs run for more than a day, you will have to adapt the above to cope with the `d-hh:mm:ss` format in the parsing.